# Import with condition clause (query) in parfile - Oracle12c

Tags: oracle, import, oracle12c

I'm trying to import specific rows from a full '.dmp' file using the parfile parameter.

**Import command:**

IMP userid=user/password@db parfile=parfile.dat

**parfile.dat file:**

[image: parfile]

But I'm receiving the error below when executing the IMP command:
[image: error received]

What can be the problem?

Is it possible to use a condition using the old **IMP** command?
If yes, why it is not working?

Thank you for your help,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As long as `PARFILE` is a valid parameter for the *original* `IMP` utility, `QUERY` is not - which answers your question:

> is it possible to use a condition using the old IMP command?

No, it is not.

> If yes, why is it not working?

Because it is not supported.

As you're on 12c, here's the [Original Import](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SUTIL/GUID-B21D5F0E-8C64-4601-9F16-25806677737B.htm#SUTIL001) documentation. Have a look at its [Parameters](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SUTIL/GUID-D3F9B4B1-F107-4499-B529-544D233811B5.htm#SUTIL1705) section - you won't find `QUERY` in there (to see the list of all parameters, expand the tree node on the left hand side of the screen).

So, what to do?

- Use Data Pump instead, if possible
- If all you have is the DMP file created with the original EXP (and you can't obtain a new, data pump one), import the whole table and write a query which will select data from it, using `WHERE` clause you meant to use in the `PARFILE`.

  - Alternatively, delete all rows that don't satisfy that condition.